# Mysql: #1064 error in stored procedure while altering

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I tried to alter the stored procedure after a successful creation.

```
DELIMITER $$
ALTER PROCEDURE `purchaseItem`(
      IN productID INT, 
      IN quantity INT,  
      IN memID INT,
      OUT stat INT)
BEGIN
            DECLARE qnty INT;
            DECLARE price decimal(10,2);
            DECLARE description VARCHAR(500);

            SET qnty = (SELECT p_Unit FROM product WHERE p_ID = productID);
            IF qnty >= quantity && qnty != 0 THEN
                SELECT p_Price INTO price FROM product WHERE p_ID = productID;
                                SELECT p_Desc INTO description FROM product WHERE p_ID = productID;
                INSERT INTO purchase VALUES 
                      (NULL, productID, quantity, price, description , memID, 0, NULL);
                UPDATE product 
                SET p_Unit = (qnty - quantity) 
                WHERE p_ID = productID;
                SET stat = 0;
            ELSE
                SET stat = 1;
            END IF;


    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But, I got the following error while trying to alter the SP.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( IN productID INT, IN quantity INT, IN memID INT, ' at line 1
```

Can someone please point out me where I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [§13.1.4 "`ALTER PROCEDURE` Syntax" in the *MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-procedure.html)

> […] you cannot change the parameters or body of a stored procedure using [the `ALTER PROCEDURE`] statement; to make such changes, you must drop and re-create the procedure using `DROP PROCEDURE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Answer (score 0):

As You can not change body of Procedure using ALTER PROCEDURE you have to DROP and Recreate the same or use some GUI tools for EDIT/UPDATE Mysql Stored Procedure.

```
ex. alter procedure employeetest sql security invoker;
```

**Note* You can change SECURITY TYPE like..INVOKER or DEFINER**

GUI Tools Freeware: [TOAD for Mysql.](http://toadformysql.com/index.jspa)